# Thread.join executing never ends

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

So I have this game loop:

```
    public void run() {
    long sleepTime;
    while (state == RUNNING) {
        long beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
        //This is where we update the game engine
        gameEngine.processGameTick();


        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                // This is where we draw the game state.
                gameEngine.drawGameFrame(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = FRAME_DELAY - ((System.nanoTime() - beforeTime)/1000000L);

        try {
            if(sleepTime > 0){
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
}
```

And when I try to kill it safely by doing this:

```
    boolean retry = true;
    gameLoop.setLoopState(GameLoop.PAUSED);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            gameLoop.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```

It never returns from `gameLoop.join()` line (I checked it with debugger).
setLoopState method is very simple, it just changes `state` field of my game loop.
Why is that so?

EDIT: I added `System.out.println("State: " + state);` line at the beginning of the while loop of game loop and it doesn't print anything after executing join() method.

EDIT2: I have an idea what can be wrong here. It would take too much place and time for you to post a code of my whole game but I'll try to explain this. Game loop executes `processGameTick()` method of my game engine which then checks for something and when it happens (condition of 'something' is fulfilled), game engine executes a method in another object which then calls `stopEngine` method which executes second code listing posted above (the one starting with `boolean retry = true`).

So does it mean that everything runs at one thread: specifically game loop thread, which eventually calls .join() on itself? If so, how can I solve it in another way?

Please tell me in case you don't uderstand what I just said. I can even make an image explaining this if you need.

Comment: The game loop thread is blocked on some call. Perhaps the lockCanvas call?

Comment: It's probably  a memory visibility issue. Is your `state` field volatile?

Comment: vsnyc: it's not. I will try to make it volatile and tell if it worked.
@JonathonReinhart: why would it be blocked by lockCanvas? Surface is still alive when I call stopping method.

Comment: @vsnyc it didn't work. BTW. read my edit on the main post please.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger? Switching to the game loop thread should show you exactly what's going on .

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do it. I mean I could set a breakpoint inside run method of my game loop but it will execute every 17 milliseconds...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart please see my latest edit on the main post.

Comment: See if [this example](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/blob/master/Examples/GraphicsCanvasBubbleSurfaceView/src/course/examples/graphics/canvasbubblesurfaceview/BubbleActivity.java) will help, especially `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()` methods. I have nothing against using a primitive to control the state but the recommended practice is to use `interrupt()` method on the respective thread.

Comment: When the thread is stuck in the `join` call, get a dump of all the threads and figure out where the game loop thread is executing. You can do this with a debugger or DDMS. My guess is you're blocked on a mutex (`synchronized`). @vsnyc: `interrupt()` would only be of use if the game loop thread were blocked in an interruptible call. It would be better to ensure that the game loop didn't block indefinitely... relying on `interrupt()` is a bit of a hack and requires correct handling of `InterruptedException` everywhere in that thread.